# ASP.NET Core 3.1 HttpClient to log only warnings and errors

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I've noticed that my application(service) that supposed to run in a backgraund creates a log of garbage logging information because of HttpClient, like so:

> info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[100]
>         Start processing HTTP request POST https://localhost:44317/programmatic/getcontent info:
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
>         Sending HTTP request POST https://localhost:44317/programmatic/getcontent info:
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
>         Received HTTP response after 3027.6345ms - OK info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
>         End processing HTTP request after 3028.2987ms - OK info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
>         Received HTTP response after 3052.4709ms - OK info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
>         End processing HTTP request after 3053.467ms - OK

Is there a way to configure it anywhere?

I inject client factory like this:

```
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient();
```

And then create a client like this:

```
HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can configure Logging in .NET Core through the Appsettings file. You should find a section in the `appsettings.json` file along the lines

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can add an additional Log Level filter to specify the minimum log level required to log.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation for Logging with filters in .NET Core can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-filter-rules-in-configuration).

Documemtation for Logging with filters in the IHttpClientFactory library can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#logging). This documentation also includes examples of log filtering with a named HttpClient.

Comment: I've set all my logging levels to warning, for everything, yet i still get information in a console. am i missing something here?

Comment: I figured out what the issue was, i redefined default loggers when i created a new Quarz Job that was doing all the HttpClient requests. Thanks For the answer!

Answer (score 12):

You can override log level in `appsettings.json` by adding, for example, a new row to the Logging object:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
    }
  },
```

This will log anything from `Warning` level and above.

Comment: I tried this, in main appsettings and in appsettings.development.... it still shows me that output in a console o_0. Anything else may be overriding these?